# Should I treat Impulse Response signal as cabinet itself?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, production, audio

I got a pack of IR signals from redwire that I can apply to my guitar in DAW and enjoy real-like cabinet sound.

Can I treat them as a cabinet itself and put in the signal chain right after the power amp (as it would be in a real world situation)?

It would go like that then:
Clean guitar signal -> pre amp (input gain knob of vst plugin) -> distortion, overdrive and effects -> power amp (output gain knob of vst plugin) -> IR signal

Would it be right if I put this in that way?

Comment: I was afraid nobody's gonna answer my question there again. And this one is kinda different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the impulse responses are meant to simulate a cabinet, then you should treat them as a cabinet.

Comment: Ok. This way I'm gonna to load them after power amp (output) of my plugin amp simulator.